# Values in Pydantic 2.4 are not converting to a model

Tags: python, celery, fastapi, pydantic

I am using Fastapi, Celery and Pydantic(2.4). The issue I'm encountering is that when I attempt to create a Model instance (`args = Model(**args)`) from a dictionary, the `setting` value is not being converted into an instance of the `SettingItem` class; instead, it becomes a dict.

How can I make the `setting` an instance of SettingItem?

```
from typing import List

from pydantic import BaseModel


class SettingItem(BaseModel):
    setting_id: str
    alias: str
    date: str


class Model(BaseModel):
    id: str
    setting: List[SettingItem]

@app.task
def get_data(args: Model):
    if isinstance(args,dict)
       args = Model.model_construct(**args)
    
    # this line throws an exception. The root cause is that args.setting is a dict instead of an instance of SettingItem
    dates = [x.date for x in args.setting]
    ...

@api.get("/")
def run(args:Model)
    get_data.delay(args.model_dumps())
```

I have tried `Model.model_validate_json()` and `Model.parse_obj()`,none of them works

Comment: Try `fromdict` from `dataclass_wizard`  lib? `fromdict(Model, args)` could help. But beware, validation is ignored this way.

Comment: What does your `args` dict look like?

Comment: @M.O. {"setting_id":"123","alias":"name","date":"2023-01-01"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, with the following test, you can see the `setting` type is `SettingItem`:

```py
d = dict(setting=[dict(setting_id='1', alias='a', date='2023')], id="1")
m = Model(**d)
print(type(m.setting[0]))
```

Out:

```
__main__.SettingItem
```

So there's nothing to do with your `pydantic` models.

It seems the problem is related to this line `get_data.delay(args.model_dumps())` as you converted the `Model` to a `dict` yourself. Therefore, obviously, you would get a `dict` within the `get_data()` method not the `Model`.

To solve the issue, you would need whether to pass the `args` without any conversion or convert it back to `Model` within the `get_data()` method as follows:

```py
@app.task
def get_data(args: dict):
    if isinstance(args, dict)
       args = Model.model_validate(args)
    ...
```

To ensure it works look at this:

```py
d = dict(setting=[dict(setting_id='1', alias='a', date='2023')], id="1")
m = Model(**d)
dd = m.model_dump()  # the thing you have done in run() method
mm = Model.model_validate(dd)  # convert it back again from dict to Model
print(type(mm.setting[0]))
```

Out:

```
__main__.SettingItem
```

---

[**NOTE**]:

- `parse_obj()` is being deprecated in *`pydantic` version 2*, so it's better to use `model_validate()` instead.